# can't set object property in put request search

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I try to point `{ $set: { info.name: req.body.name   }` an error throws.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'.
How to do it properly?

Code:

```
app.put('/users/updateMyOwnInfo', ValidateCookies, (req, res) => {

    db.collection('users').updateOne({ id: parseInt(req.cookies.userId) }, 
    { $set: { info.name: req.body.name   } }, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.status(500)
        }
        res.send(doc)
    })
})
```

Comment: I tried this warriant as well. { $set: { info: {...info, name: req.body.name}   } }

Comment: We can point you at more specific answers if you explain what `db.collection` is. I'm guessing Mongoose....?

Comment: I don't use MongoDB, but if I were a betting man, I'd think: `$set: { info: {name: req.body. name}}`.

Comment: It works, but my old data deleted. I think I need to make a copy initially

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know if it would do a merge. :-|